How to solve flickering screen problem in Ubuntu 24.04.1 LTS
I have installed Ubuntu 24.04.1 LTS on my Asus laptop. Sometimes my screen starts to flicker until I move the cursor. It doesn't happen while I watch videos. I have an Nvidia MX graphic card. I tried disabling it but nothing happened.
